# Is it possible to link to an external htm page?

Tags: hyperlink, external

I have a review box on my website that has 10 or more reviews. Since it's all text it's getting crawled and indexed. I'd rather it didn't get crawled and I've placed the google:off and google:on idea that I discovered. However that may only work for a googlebot crawl, if at all. I was thinking if the review box could link to the text in an external htm page, like you can to a css page, then that might prevent it from being crawled and still load into the space accordingly. I don't know, is this possible?? Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an excellent solution on my own, and would like to share it...

I created an iframe for my review box and styled it for width, height, and border in my css. Within the iframe tag I put src="reviewstext.htm". I then created this htm page and copied and pasted all my reviews. Within the head tag of the page I put...

meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"

link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css"

Also, for some reason the iframe tag takes on the same background color as the body of your site. In my case it was a blue colour. I wanted my iframe to have a white background instead. The css styling didn't seem to work but styling the body tag in my reviewstext.htm file did the trick... like below.

body style="background-color: transparent;"

So, I now have a reviews box that refers to an external page. Not only does the text on that external page not get crawled, but the text is not on my homepage either for crawlers to see. With this change my keyword ratios are back in line and not obscured by all the review text... :o)